# Get stylesheet from upload folder Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a project and I want to enqueue a stylesheet file located in

`http://mysite.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/custom/master.css`

So I wrote this line of code

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/uploads/2016/custom/master.css', false,'1.1','all');
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? When something doesn't work, always describe in detail what you expected and how what really happens differs from what you expected. Did you get an error? If yes, then what is the exact error message?

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/uploads/2016/custom/master.css" />
```

Add the above link in your `header.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `content_url()` function to get `wp-content` directory url instead of template directory,

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', content_url().'/uploads/2016/custom/master.css', false,'1.1','all');
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can change custom-style and then try the bottom code

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'uniqueid-custom-style', site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2016/custom/master.css', false,'1.1','all');
```